# Navigation tab in Markdown

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Is it possible to create in GitHub's Markdown a navigation tab like this one?

https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/#examples

[image: GitHub navigation tabs in a GitHub page]

Comment: There are no such tabs at the link shown.

Comment: The page has changed, but the question still applies. The image gives enough information.

Comment: This may be related: [Add tabbed code snippets in markdown](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/17381).

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in way to do this, but you can make multiple, similarly structured documents to achieve the same functionality.

Create multiple .md files with the same content in each file, only make the stuff under the navigation tab different. You can then add navigation links on the top, which should point to these different .md files you just created. You can make the active link bold on each page to make it easily differentiable.

Comment: Would you mind explaining this?

Comment: @Erwann Sure, let me know which part is unclear and I'll explain it further.

Comment: For one, how do you create the tabs?

Comment: @Erwann Just make links using the [Link text](example.com) syntax, which point to the different Markdown files.

Comment: Ivan Perez submitted a snapshot of github page with heading `Examples`, and just below a string of tabs. I guess these are links to thumbnails `![thumbnail](assets/text-thumbnail.png)`.